# Self join a table and use row only once - proper usage of DENSE_RANK()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First, some made up data:

```
create table #testm
(
    transdate date,
    item nvarchar(20),
    qty int,
    whse nvarchar(10),
    loc nvarchar(10)
)
insert into #testm (transdate, item, qty, whse, loc)
values ('20180601', '123', 100, 'main', 'qc'),
       ('20180602', '123', -100, 'main', 'qc'), 
       ('20180603', '123', 100, 'main', 'qc'),
       ('20180604', '123', -100, 'main', 'qc'), 
       ('20180602', '1234', 100, 'main', 'qc'), 
       ('20180602', '1234', -100, 'main', 'notqc')
```

The scenario:
I have a table where all my transaction like stock moves and others are recorded. I need to generate a report, which will show data (the `#testm` table fields) for items entering a specific `loc`, and then exiting it. However, I need to only count each "exit" once, so it does not join itself to every other "entry" which matches the item and quantity. Then, I need to see how much time the item spent in that `loc`. Special case is when item hasn't left the `loc` yet, where it should show nulls in 2nd part of quesry with `datediff()` from `getdate()`.

In the above `insert` statement, the expected result is to match row 1 with 2, 3 with 4, 5 with nothing (as there's no exit yet, and row 6 has incorrect `loc`) and skip row 6 since `loc` is not the one i'm looking for.

Result should look like that

```
     transdate  item qty whse loc td2        it2  qt2   wh2     lo2 datediffhour
     2018-06-01 123  100 main qc  2018-06-02 123  -100  main    qc   24
     2018-06-02 1234 100 main qc  NULL       NULL NULL  NULL    NULL 1056
     2018-06-03 123  100 main qc  2018-06-04 123  -100  main    qc   24
```

Here's my try at it:

```
select * from
(
    select tin.transdate, tin.item, tin.qty, tin.whse, tin.loc, DENSE_RANK() over(partition by tin.transdate order by tout.transdate) as firstrank,
    DENSE_RANK() over (partition by tout.transdate order by tin.item) as secondrank, tout.transdate as td2, tout.item as it2, tout.qty as qt2, tout.whse as wh2, tout.loc as lo2,
    datediff(hour, tin.transdate, isnull(tout.transdate, getdate())) as datediffhour
    from #testm as tin
    left join #testm as tout on tin.item = tout.item and tin.whse = tout.whse and tin.transdate <= tout.transdate and tin.qty = -1*tout.qty
where tin.loc = 'qc' and tout.loc = 'qc'
) as t
where (firstrank = secondrank or t.td2 is null) and t.qty > 0
order by t.transdate
```

**2 problems with it:**

It skips row 5

`secondrank` and `firstrank` is just guesswork, as I'm not really familliar with `DENSE_RANK` - am I even using it right?

Comment: if you are joining just to top 1, then cross apply or outer apply is worth considering

Comment: so you can do something along the lines of * select t1.item, OA.item from #test t1 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #test t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id) AS OA *

Comment: @Yuropoor . . . Desired results *as a text table* would be a big help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added a result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`. Only one is required here. Note that we have a `t_in.transdate < t_out.transdate` condition instead of `<=`.

The key to show row 5 with no exit matching is putting the condition `t_out.loc = 'qc'` as left join condition instead of **`WHERE` clause, because in here it acts like you were applying `INNER JOIN`**.

```
select 
  transdate, item, qty, whse, loc,
  td2, it2, qt2, wh2, lo2, datediffhour
from (
    select 
      t_in.transdate, t_in.item, t_in.qty, t_in.whse, t_in.loc,
      t_out.transdate as td2, t_out.item as it2, t_out.qty as qt2, t_out.whse as wh2, t_out.loc as lo2,
      datediff(hour, t_in.transdate, isnull(t_out.transdate, getdate())) as datediffhour,
      row_number() over (partition by t_in.item, t_in.transdate order by t_in.transdate) as rn
    from #testm t_in
    left join #testm t_out on
      t_in.item = t_out.item
      and t_in.whse = t_out.whse
      and t_in.qty = -1 * t_out.qty
      and t_in.transdate < t_out.transdate
      and t_out.loc = 'qc' 
    where 
      t_in.qty > 0
      and t_in.loc = 'qc'     
) t 
where rn = 1 -- pick up only first matching "exit"
order by transdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Row_Number()`. This won't work when you buy same items for the same location consecutively and sell them afterwards (enter/exit).

```
Select * from 
  (Select test1.*,      
      datediff(hour, test1.transdate, Coalesce(test2.transdate, getdate())) as datediffhour,
      row_number() over (partition by test1.item, test1.loc, test1.transdate order by test1.transdate) as ranking
    from #testm test1
    left join #testm test2 
    on test1.item = test2.item
   and test1.loc = test2.loc 
   and test1.whse = test2.whse
   and test1.qty + test2.qty = 0
   and test1.transdate < test2.transdate
    where test1.qty > 0)c
where ranking=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer apply`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*, tnext.*
from #testm t outer apply
     (select top (1) tnext.*
      from #testm tnext
      where tnext.loc = t.loc and tnext.item = t.item and
            tnext.transdate > t.transdate
      order by tnext.transdate asc
     ) tnext;
```